# Outer-shell music buttons like in iOS

Tags: lock-screens, music-player

I just dumped my iOS device for the sake of Android (iTunes, flash lack and other reasons).

I'm trying to retain the features I got used to on the iOS.

One of them was the ability to start, pause, skip etc. in music while screen is locked:

**Important:**
I'm an Android noob (I'm a .NET dev), I believe there has to be a way to control the device's music in a player-agnostic manner, so I'm rather looking for a "music controls lock-screen" or "music controls FOR my lock-screen" application rather than a "music player with ls controls".

[image]

Is there any similar app/feature on Android?

My device: [Samsung Galaxy S WiFi 5.0 (YP-G70)](http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/mp3-players/YP-G70CWY/XAA).

**Note** my device is locked with a lock pattern.

[image]

*Pictures are downloaded from the web and are for illustration purposes, they do not reflect my own phone / settings.

Comment: Have you simply tried this? It works out of the box with the default Music app on, like, every device I've seen.

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes I tried **this**. and it's cucumbers. I mean it's close to sulfur but is like warehouses. Got me? I didn't get you either.

Comment: Didn't get what? Start the music app. Lock your screen. Turn it back on. Have you tried that? Do you see music controls when you turn the screen back on? Every reasonably recent device I've ever seen has them. If you don't then you may want to include your specific device in your question.

Comment: I didn't know what you mean, sorry. Be sure I tried that. I tuned on the music, while it's playing I lock the screen, when I press the on/off button I only see the plain lock screen - no music buttons.

Comment: @eldarerathis the default Music app on my Gingerbread Galaxy S has never supported this, I'm sure many others don't too

Comment: @GAThrawn: Yeesh, that seems like a pretty glaring omission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my solution. This feature is provided in [Go Locker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jiubang.goscreenlock).

It's so great, and works with Google Music as well!  Very customizable and there are zillion of themes out there.
And most important, it's free.

I'm sure you now think I'm affiliated with them, the truth is yes, I use their products and I'm addicted to them, that's it!

Answer (score 7):

If your built-in music app and lock screen doesn't do this currently, then you can try using [WinAmp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp) as your player, that was the first music app I saw that added the transport controls to your lock screen.

Go into WinAmp's settings to find this option:

[image: Use lock-screen player option in WinAmp]

Then it should look a bit like this when your phone is locked:

[image: Locked phone with WinAmp's lock screen player]

These days most music apps include this feature (I believe including [Google Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music) or [Amazon MP3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.mp3) if you're in the US), try searching the Market for something like [lock screen music control](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=lock+screen+music+control&c=apps) to see a selection.

This feature either needs to be built into which ever app you're using to play your music (as above) or you need to switch to using a different lock screen that supports widgets, such as [WidgetLocker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker) and then you can choose from available music control add-ons like [Media Buttons](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.mediabuttons) or [Phantom Music Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.jhg.musiccontrolwidget).

Comment: Yeah, Google Music should definitely do this (does for me). So do Songbird and Amazon's music player/MP3 store.

Comment: OK. Do you know of any app that will enable lock-screen buttons for the default player?

Comment: @elderathis they'd be a great option, it's a pity neither are functional players unless you're in the US

Comment: @eldarerathis I have GMusic installed, but no buttons. Just lock screen.

Comment: @Shimmy: I wonder if that's got something to do with Samsung's Touchwiz interface, then. Is it the version of Google Music (I guess "Google Play Music", now...ick) that's in the Market or something pre-installed?

Comment: @Shimmy see the edit with options for placing widgets on alternate lock-screens

Comment: I didn't install the WinAmp player and don't mean to. I need to have the Android player + GMusic do it. BTW, note that the screen is locked with a lock pattern.

Comment: @Shimmy See my final paragraph where I mention ways to add lock screen widgets that will work with the built-in player. As far as I know all of the klock screen music controls work fine with a pattern lock, on my screenshot above pressing the padlock icon hides the music controls and takes you straight to the pattern.

Comment: @Shimmy : try https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miui.home . Some of it themes gives you the option of opening the music player on the lock screen

Answer (score 1):

Missed the the same thing when I switched from IOS to Android. 
Don't know if this solves all of your issues, but supports generic controls (notification, widgets, etc) for most media applications.

[Media Utilities](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.batescorp.notificationmediacontrols.alpha&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5iYXRlc2NvcnAubm90aWZpY2F0aW9ubWVkaWFjb250cm9scy5hbHBoYSJd)

Answer (score 0):

Well what i love about Android is that you can be assured you kind of get more than what you just got out of the box. You are not limited to only what has been shipped. My suggestion is go download widget locker. it allows you to add widgets on lock screens.

Comment: I never pay for apps :}
And yes, I'm a dev too. Public apps should be paid by ads :P

Answer (score -3):

Try N 7 player, it supports what you desire and a lot more..

Comment: I'm looking for a lock-screen that will be integrated with device music status, I believe there should be a general way to control music of the device in an application-agnostic manner.